# CloudBees Eclipse Toolkit with Git

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, cloudbees

I'm trying to setup the CloudBees Eclipse Toolkit to connect to my CloudBees Git repository, but it doesn't list the Git repository in the list of available repositories. If I create a CloudBees SVN repository, then it finds that repository fine. It also finds the Jenkins build profiles as well.

Here is the CloudBees tutorial for the plugin, but it only lists an SVN connection: http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/Documentation/CloudBeesEclipseToolkit

I know my Git repository is setup because I can connect to it with command line and the EGit eclipse plugin just fine. The CloudBees plugin simply doesn't see it as an option, despite it saying it supports Git repositories on a CloudBees account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git repositories from cloudbees forge are not yet supported in CloudBees eclipse plugin. You have to manually configure EGit with the repository URL.
This will be included in a future release, as required changes in EGit/JGit are available

Comment: Thanks for the information. I suspected this much. Hopefully, it gets added soon!

Answer (score 1):

CloudBees Eclipse Toolkit(v2.0) now supports Git repositories. If moving from a previous version to the current version (2.0), you need to re-install EGit (2.2.x+).

The older wiki page in the question has been superseded by a [page specific to the newer version](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/EclipseToolkitv2.0)